# Where do the exception codes used in ADPlus.config come from?

Tags: asp.net, windbg, adplus

I've been trying to put together a config file for ADPlus.exe to determine the cause of my ASP.NET application's unexpected restarts. I'm having some trouble understanding the `adplus.config` file.

I have found example config files online, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6653585/645511), that contain `<Exception Code="xxx">` sections. The sections look like this:

```
<Exception Code="sov"><!-- StackOverflow -->
    <Actions1>VOID</Actions1>
    <Actions2>Log;Time;Stack;MiniDump;EventLog</Actions2>
    <ReturnAction1>GN</ReturnAction1>
    <ReturnAction2>GN</ReturnAction2>
</Exception>
```

Where do the three letter abbreviations for each exception come from? How do I know that `sov` means a StackOverflowException? I have tried to find a list of these abbreviations online, but despite trying various combinations of search terms, I have come up empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have always used the WinDbg sx command to list all codes,
Not sure if this is 100% correct, but have never seen others.

```
0:000> sx
  ct - Create thread - ignore
  et - Exit thread - ignore
  cpr - Create process - ignore
```

-- cut here, a lot more before:

```
 sbo - Stack buffer overflow - break - not handled
 sov - Stack overflow - break - not handled
```

Comment: Perfect. That is exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thank you so much.